# Invoke the most specific overload in a statically compiled Groovy

Tags: groovy, dynamic, overloading, metaprogramming, overload-resolution

Due to the Groovy dynamic method dispatch the below code prints `ABC` which is what I expect. After adding `@CompileStatic` my code breaks printing just `AAA`. How can I preserve the logic of dynamic method choice and have the code statically compiled?

```
class PatternMatching {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        [new A(), new B(), new C()].each {
            show it
        }
    }

    static void show(A a) {
        print 'A'
    }

    static void show(B b) {
        print 'B'
    }

    static void show(C c) {
        print 'C'
    }
}

class A {}

class B extends A {}

class C extends A {}
```

Surprisingly even `instanceof` with cast does not work at all for statically compiled Groovy:

```
if (it instanceof A) {
    show it as A
} else if (it instanceof B) {
    show it as B
} else if (it instanceof C) {
    show it as C
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Groovy 2.1.0, you can use `@groovy.transform.CompileDynamic` annotation to declare which part of the code has to be invoked dynamically. In this case, you can extract `show(a)` method invocation to a separate method that is annotated with `@CompileDynamic`. The remaining part of your code will get compiled statically, with this small exception to `show(a)` method invocation.

Consider the following example:

```groovy
import groovy.transform.CompileDynamic
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class PatternMatching {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        [new A(), new B(), new C()].each {
            callShowDynamically(it)
        }
    }

    @CompileDynamic
    static void callShowDynamically(A a) {
        show a
    }

    static void show(A a) {
        print 'A'
    }

    static void show(B b) {
        print 'B'
    }

    static void show(C c) {
        print 'C'
    }
}

@CompileStatic
class A {}

@CompileStatic
class B extends A {}

@CompileStatic
class C extends A {}
```

And here is a side by side comparison of the decompiled `PatternMatching.class`. *(The one on the right side represents a statically compiled class with `@CompileDynamic` method.)*

[image]

And here is a side by side comparison of the `each` closure decompiled class bytecode:

[image]

Pay attention to one detail - even when we use `callShowDynamically()` method that was annotated with the `@CompileDynamic`, its invocation at the bytecode level uses statically compiled type, and it even casts it to an `A` type:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    final class _main_closure1 extends Closure implements GeneratedClosure {
        public _main_closure1(Object _outerInstance, Object _thisObject) {
            super(_outerInstance, _thisObject);
        }

        public Object doCall(Object it) {
            return PatternMatching.callShowDynamically((A)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(it, A.class));
        }

        public Object call(Object args) {
            return this.doCall(args);
        }

        public Object call() {
            return this.doCall((Object)null);
        }

        @Generated
        public Object doCall() {
            return this.doCall((Object)null);
        }
    }

    DefaultGroovyMethods.each(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createList(new Object[]{new A(), new B(), new C()}), new _main_closure1(PatternMatching.class, PatternMatching.class));
}
```

What makes this invocation "dynamic" is the implementation of the `PatternMatching.callShowDynamically()` method:

```
public static Object callShowDynamically(A a) {           
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();                
    return var1[0].callStatic(PatternMatching.class, a); 
}
```

This method uses [Groovy's MOP (Meta-Object Protocol)](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html) to detect (based on the runtime specific type) what is the most specific method for that type to invoke. At the compiler level, it is stil only `PatternMatching.callShowDynamically((A)value)` method invocation, so it has no idea that other methods may be invoked instead. And that is why your IntelliJ IDEA sees `show(B b)` and `show(C c)` methods as unused because there is no explicit call to any of those two methods.

Comment: Issue with that approach is that IntelliJ IDEA does not understand dynamic invocation and shows methods as unused. Maybe there is just another syntax to express the same intent?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an issue with this approach. My IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 Ulitmate sees `show(B b)` and `show(C c)` as unused methods in all the cases, no matter if there is no `@CompileStatic`, a single `@CompileStatic`, or `@CompileStatic` + `@CompileDynamic`.

Comment: Yes, I have the same and I'd like to avoid it. E.g. some kind of pattern matching or instanceof and casting to show all methods as used.

Comment: I guess you won't get anything like that. Keep in mind that even in dynamic-only Groovy use case, the `show it` method invocation in your closure gets compiled to something like this: `PatternMatching.show((A)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(it, A.class));` The compiler sees only single usage of `show(it)`  method - the one that casts parameter to a `A` type. The dynamic nature of Groovy is fully runtime based - because of the complex Meta-Object Protocol, Groovy uses `invokeMethod` intermediate method to determine which method should be executed at the runtime.

Comment: It would probably skip marking `show(B b)` and `show(C c)` methods as unused if the IntelliJ IDEA's Groovy plugin executed your code constantly and used information from the runtime. As far as I know, it uses only information that is compile-time based, which makes sense.